# combining >> output.log and 2>&1 | tee output.log

Tags: bash, shell, unix, redirect

I use the following command for displaying and storing the output and error:

```
command 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

I often tent to store the output in the same log file as follows:

```
command2 >> output.log
```

What I would like to do is to combine these two and be able to display the output and save it in the same log file. I have tried `command2 >> | tee output.log` and several other things but could not manage to do that! Is there any quick solution to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `-a` flag, `tee` will append the output to files.

```
command2 | tee -a output.log
```